# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 21596 y sizes: 7199 Please provide data which shares the same first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am new to Keras and deep learning in general. I am trying to train an LSTM autoencoder to compress a multivariate time series, consisting of 120 features and about 28K timestamps, into a latent representation that I can use for supervised learning later. In the process, I encountered an error with data cardinality. I understand this to be an error with the sizes of my input data. But I'm not sure how to resolve this. My tensorflow version is 2.3.0

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard


import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)

def generate_datasets_for_training(data, window_size,scale=True, scaler_type=StandardScaler):
  _l = len(data)
  data = scaler_type().fit_transform(data)
  Xs = []
  Ys = []
  for i in range(0, (_l - window_size)):
    # because this is an autoencoder - our Ys are the same as our Xs. No need to pull the next sequence of values
    Xs.append(data[i:i+window_size])
    Ys.append(data[i:i+window_size])
  tr_x, tr_y, ts_x, ts_y = [np.array(x) for x in train_test_split(Xs, Ys)]
  assert tr_x.shape[2] == ts_x.shape[2] == (data.shape[1] if (type(data) == np.ndarray) else len(data))
  return  (tr_x.shape[2], tr_x, tr_y, ts_x, ts_y)

def plot_history(history):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(history.history["loss"])
    plt.title("Train loss")
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(history.history["val_loss"])
    plt.title("Test loss")
    


sample_data = pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv")
sample_data = sample_data.drop('time', axis=1)

epochs = 100
batch_size = 32
window_length = 4


early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-2, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto',
    baseline=None, restore_best_weights=True)

feats, X, Y, XX, YY = generate_datasets_for_training(sample_data, 4)

print('feats:' + str(feats))
print("X shape: " + str(X.shape))
print("Y shape: " + str(Y.shape))
print("XX shape: " + str(XX.shape))
print("YY shape: " + str(YY.shape))


model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', batch_input_shape=(None, window_length, feats), return_sequences=True, name='encoder_1'))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='encoder_2'))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(16, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=False, name='encoder_3'))
model.add(keras.layers.RepeatVector(window_length, name='encoder_decoder_bridge'))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(16, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='decoder_1'))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='decoder_2'))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', return_sequences=True, name='decoder_3'))
model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(feats)))
model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer='adam')
model.build()
print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(x=X, y=Y, validation_data=(XX, YY), epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, callbacks=[early_stop])
print(history)

plot_history(history)
```

This is the error I get when I run this:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 21596
  y sizes: 7199
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

When I print out the shapes of the input data, this is what I get:

```
X shape: (21596, 4, 119)
Y shape: (7199, 4, 119)
XX shape: (21596, 4, 119)
YY shape: (7199, 4, 119)
```

Thank you to anyone who can help, it is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an error in your `model.fit()`, better try this :

```
history = model.fit(x=X, y=XX, validation_data=(Y, YY), epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, callbacks=[early_stop])
```

You have to get the same number of samples in your train and validation dataset